# How to add items to numpy array mapped to each dictionary key in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have created a dictionary as ,

```
dummy_dict = {'current_acc':np.empty(0,dtype='int'),
              'saving_acc':np.empty(0,dtype='int'),
              'fixed_acc':np.empty(0,dtype='int')}
```

I would like to fill values in numpy array value of each key in dictionary using loops,

let's, say on meeting a condition each key value should be filled in with True(1) else it should be False(0).

Below statements explains why it is requirered.

I have a custom function to create a dummy variables of given column,

```
def py_step_dummy(DT,col,drop_level=False):

    dummy_dict={ item : [] for item in dt.unique(DT[:,f[col]]).to_list()[0]}

    dummy_values=DT[:,f[col]].to_list()[0]

    for item in dummy_values:
        for key in dummy_dict.keys():
            if item==key:
                dummy_dict[key].append(1)
            else:
                dummy_dict[key].append(0)

    dummy_dt = dt.Frame(dummy_dict) 

   return dummy_dt
```

Here I would like to replace this dictionary

```
dummy_dict={ item : [] for item in dt.unique(DT[:,f[col]]).to_list()[0]}
```

as

```
dummy_dict={ item : np.empty(0) for item in dt.unique(DT[:,f[col]]).to_list()[0]}
```

In my case dictionary with numpy arrays values would only be allowed and suggested.

could you now please help me how to do it ?.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. What is the problem to work with `dummy_dict['current_acc']` like with any other array. The only problem is that you created empty array and it is not normal `list` which has `append()` to add item. Use array with expected size ie. aarray for ten elements `np.empty(10,dtype='int')` and then you can do `dummy_dict['current_acc'][0] = 0`, `dummy_dict['current_acc'][1] = 0`, etc.  OR use normal list instead of `numpy array` and then you can use `dummy_dict['current_acc'].append(0)`, etc.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. i have just edited the question where np arrays are required in my case. i'm Ok with appending list values, but my case would require them to be Numpy arrays

Comment: `array` doesn't have `append()` and at start you should define it with expected final size - `np.empyt(size)` and then you can use `dummy_dict[key][position] = 1`

Comment: OR maybe convert all lists to arrays after you put all values in lists.

Comment: Yeah let my try these two things. I will update yours here once it’s done

Comment: BTW: you can use `int(item==key)` to convert `True/False` to `1/0` and then you can run `dummy_dict[key][position] = int(item==key)` without `if/else`

Comment: For now I have opted for converting a list to np array in each key. it worked out. i will try out other solutions as well after sometime